Java (Spring) / MongoDB: If-Conditional set() Function
I want to modify my MongoDB through Java with the Springframework (no other).
In MongoDB it should look like this:
Documents.update(
    {some_condition: true, "some field": "some condition"}, 
    {$set: {"status": "value 1"}},
    {multi: true},
    function(err, numAffected) {
        Documents.update(
            {some_condition: true, "some field": {$ne: "some condition"}}, 
            {$set: {"status": "value 2"}},
            {multi: true},
            function(err, numAffected) {
                // All done.
            }
        )
    }
)


Now I need your help with transfering it into Java (Spring Framework).
Thanks you.
I'm not that good in using Queries in Java, therefore I didn't try that much.

Are you trying to use if-else in to perform the Update?
I would recommend looking at the $cond operator to make use of the if else conditions.
You can use the below example to convert using the $cond operator
db.documents.updateMany(
    { some_condition: true },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                status: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: { $eq: ["$some field", "some condition"] },
                        then: "value 1",
                        else: "value 2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);

and the equivalent Java code would look like below:
public void updateDocuments() {
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("someCondition").is(true));
        
        Update update = new Update();
        update.set("status",
                new Document("$cond", 
                    new Document("if", new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$someField", "some condition")))
                        .append("then", "value 1")
                        .append("else", "value 2")
                )
        );

        mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Document.class);
    }

